# Magento2: Flat rate and table rate shipping not showing at backend

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, backend

I'm using magento version 2.1.4 for my one of the eCommerce website. I've enabled flat rate and table rate from backend. It works perfectly when placing order from frontend. However, when I try to create order from backend, it doesn't show those methods and instead showing message "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order."

Does anyone knows the fix for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've reported the issue to Magento as well https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13510

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?